# Do prefectures in France accept multiple tax stamps (timbres fiscaux) for a total amount?

Tags: france, study, permits, visa-renewals

This was my first application for a student residence permit in Lyon, France. At the time of the application, they informed me that the amount of tax to pay will be 49€ (For 1-year) or 79€ (For >1 year). They told me that I will receive an SMS stating the amount.

So far, I did not receive any SMS from the prefecture but through an email inquiry, I was informed that my card is ready to collect. However, even on follow-up they failed to mention the total amount of tax I have to pay.

I am planning to visit and collect my card at the prefecture. However, as I don't have an exact amount, here is what I thought I could do. Maybe someone can correct me.

I plan to buy two stamps online, one for 49€ and one for 30€.

1) If they ask for 49€ stamp, I will hand the first one.

2) But if they ask for 79€, I give them both stamps.

My question is whether 2) is an acceptable thing to do here and do prefectures allow cumulative stamps.

If this helps: I'm an Indian student.

Another question,
They mention this "Vous devez régler une taxe et un droit de timbre de 79 € par timbres fiscaux ordinaires." Does that mean they do not accept the online tax stamps?

Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: It's been a while since I last used any of those (last time I did you couldn't buy them online), but my impression is that if you buy them in a "bureau de tabac" then you can indeed use several (note the plural in "timbres fiscaux ordinaires"), while if you buy it online you can only use one as they need to enter the number or use the QR Code and I wouldn't be surprised if they could only enter one. I think the "ordinaire" is rather as opposed to "timbre amende". Not a definite or sourced answer though, hence the comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally timbres fiscaux are basically like money, you can just add them up to whatever the total should be as if they were bills. No idea whether online ones would be acceptable, but you can always run into an older fonctionnaire who thinks online is vaporware and refuses them, so you'd do best to buy them at the local tobacco shop.  The main problem of course is that if you're only due the smaller amount you're basically out 30E, as they're not really negotiable for anything else.  Why don't you try an inquiry at the email that wrote to inform you of the card's availability?  They might not answer, but you might get a hint if someone was well-disposed that day..